# Program crashed while compiling and executing Qt5 project with Assimp

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, assimp

I want to implement a program that can load 3D model into OpenGL using Assimp([link of Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/index.html)).

My Qt version is 5.3.2.
I use Qt Creator and modify the `.pro` file to import Assimp library:

```
INCLUDEPATH += H:\Study\assimp-3.1.1-win-binaries\assimp-3.1.1-win-binaries\include\assimp
LIBS += -lH:\Study\assimp-3.1.1-win-binaries\assimp-3.1.1-win-binaries\lib32\assimp
```

Then I try to read `box.obj` in my program:

```
#include <scene.h>
#include <postprocess.h>
#include <Importer.hpp>

int main(){
    Assimp::Importer importer;

    const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile("box.obj", NULL);

    if (!scene)
    {
        qDebug() << "Error loading file: (assimp:) " << importer.GetErrorString();
        return false;
    }

    .....// Other code to create a window

    return 0;
}
```

Then the compiling finish without error.
Then the program crashed just after starting.

> Starting G:\QtProject\QtTest\build-MyOpenGL-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2010_OpenGL_32bit-Debug\debug\MyOpenGL.exe...
>
> G:\QtProject\QtTest\build-MyOpenGL-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2010_OpenGL_32bit-Debug\debug\MyOpenGL.exe crashed

I try to debug but the breakpoints seems not work.

And I delete some code and just declare `scene`:

```
#include <scene.h>
#include <postprocess.h>
#include <Importer.hpp>

int main(){
    //Assimp::Importer importer;

    const aiScene* scene;  // = importer.ReadFile("box.obj", NULL);

    /*if (!scene)
    {
        qDebug() << "Error loading file: (assimp:) " << importer.GetErrorString();
        return false;
    }*/

    .....// Other code to create a window

    return 0;
}
```

the program can run again!

And I'm really confused now. Can anyone help me?

Comment: And my compiler is Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 10.0

Answer (score 2):

Add the dynamic libraries to the debug/release(Acoording to your compilation output in the debug) directory of the Qt. 
the programs without the quoted code :

```
ReadFile("box.obj", NULL);
GetErrorString();
```

will work because it doesn't call for a function in the dynamic library , that's why it's called dynamic library .
Also write :

```
LIBS += -L/path not -l
```

Comment: I add dynamic libraries to both debug and release directory. And I try to compile in both debug and release mode. But the problem is not solved.

Comment: By the way, `ReadFile` and `GetErrorString` are class function of `Assimp::Importer`, I cannot use these functions without an `Assimp::Importer` object. And the LIBS += -l follows the static library file but not the directory. Qt will add `.lib` to the file name automatically.

Comment: Did you add also the dll files ? Plus did you make sure that you are using the libs for the right architecture (32/64 bit)?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I add dll files and I'm sure that I use the libs for the right architecture. What's more, I run the exe file after building my project, and there's the error:`The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)`

Comment: based on the Windows Error Codes [Doc](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CIYBEBYwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F9%2F5%2FE%2F95EF66AF-9026-4BB0-A41D-A4F81802D92C%2F%5BMS-ERREF%5D.pdf&ei=17GoT53mCK_R4QSGm6WRCQ&usg=AFQjCNHu2-WVJpA7ViG5e-GAne_gCH9Rzw&sig2=f1N9anRoFy8qDuth62oK7g), this Error Code means: 0xC000007B STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT:Which is a good indication that the 32-bit app tried to load a 64-bit DLL .

Comment: i suggest that you verify that the compiler used to compile the assim libraries is the same that you are using in Qt , plus check if all Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio be also appropriate (architecture and version).